# Proving that this number is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Liouville's Constant is defined as follows:

$$\begin{align}
L_{10} &= \sum^\infty_{n=1}10^{-n!} \\
&=0.\mathbf{1}\text{(no zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(3 zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(17 zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(95 zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(599 zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(4319 zeros)}\mathbf{1}\text{(35279 zeros)}\ldots
\end{align}$$

Notice that $\forall~n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, the $n$th and $(n+1)$th occurrences of $1$ are separated by $nn!-1$ zeros.

Now let $\Lambda$ be the constant formed by summing the reciprocals of the numbers of zeros between each subsequent occurrence of the digit $1$ in Liouville's Constant:

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle\Lambda &= \sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{nn!-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{95}+\frac{1}{599}+\frac{1}{4319}+\frac{1}{35279}+\frac{1}{322559}+\frac{1}{3265919}+\ldots \\
&= 0.40461594459112144123383699845748495376409240909536\ldots
\end{align}$$

How can I (dis)prove that $\Lambda$ is irrational?

Comment: That number is transcendental. There's a proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number , https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(Number_Theory)

Comment: @EthanBolker I was talking about the second constant, not the first.

Comment: Note that there's no role for $10$ left in the definition of your constant, so the subscrit probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: @ElEctric I suspect the denominators grow fast enough so that Liouville's theorem applies: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(Number_Theory)